# Trying to connect themeroller to my datepicker Calendar

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker

Im trying to style my calendar that i downloaded from here:

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html?#controls

Ive themed it here:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

now ive downloaded it, but, im unsure how to connect the css properly so that the calendar in my page is styled exactly how i did it in the themeroller app. Ive tried reading the documentation Keith provides, but it seems sorta hazy to me and im not getting it right when trying to connect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure you have the theme call on your css

```
<link type="text/css" href="../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Your calendar should now have the theme

and you can use the theme's classes for other elements:

```
class="ui-corner-all
```

This demo doc always helps me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){

    // Accordion
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

    //Autocomplete
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
     source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby", "python", "c", "scala", "groovy", "haskell", "perl"]
    });

    // Button
    $("#button").button();
    $("#radioset").buttonset();

    // Tabs
    $('#tabs').tabs();


    // Dialog   
    $('#dialog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     width: 600,
     buttons: {
      "Ok": function() { 
       $(this).dialog("close"); 
      }, 
      "Cancel": function() { 
       $(this).dialog("close"); 
      } 
     }
    });

    // Dialog Link
    $('#dialog_link').click(function(){
     $('#dialog').dialog('open');
     return false;
    });

    // Datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     inline: true
    });

    // Slider
    $('#slider').slider({
     range: true,
     values: [17, 67]
    });

    // Progressbar
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
     value: 20 
    });

    //hover states on the static widgets
    $('#dialog_link, ul#icons li').hover(
     function() { $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover'); }, 
     function() { $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover'); }
    );

   });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
   /*demo page css*/
   body{ font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
   .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
   #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
   #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
   ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
   ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
   ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
  </style> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Welcome to jQuery UI!</h1>
 <p style="font-size: 1.3em; line-height: 1.5; margin: 1em 0; width: 50%;">This page demonstrates the widgets you downloaded using the theme you selected in the download builder. We've included and linked to minified versions of <a href="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">jQuery</a>, your personalized copy of <a href="js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js">jQuery UI (js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js)</a>, and <a href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css">css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css</a> which imports the entire jQuery UI CSS Framework. You can choose to link a subset of the CSS Framework depending on your needs. </p>
 <p style="font-size: 1.2em; line-height: 1.5; margin: 1em 0; width: 50%;">You've downloaded components and a theme that are compatible with jQuery 1.3+. Please make sure you are using jQuery 1.3+ in your production environment.</p> 

 <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 2em 0 1em; font-size: 1.3em;">YOUR COMPONENTS:</p>

  <!-- Accordion -->
  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Accordion</h2>
  <div id="accordion">
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
    <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
    <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Autocomplete -->
  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Autocomplete</h2>
  <div>
   <input id="autocomplete" style="z-index: 100; position: relative" title="type &quot;a&quot;" />
  </div>


  <!-- Button -->
  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Button</h2>
  <button id="button">A button element</button>
  <form style="margin-top: 1em;">
   <div id="radioset">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
   </div>
  </form>


  <!-- Tabs -->
  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Tabs</h2>
  <div id="tabs">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="tabs-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
   <div id="tabs-2">Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh. Cras orci urna, blandit id, pretium vel, aliquet ornare, felis. Maecenas scelerisque sem non nisl. Fusce sed lorem in enim dictum bibendum.</div>
   <div id="tabs-3">Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis, sollicitudin eu, felis. Pellentesque nisi urna, interdum eget, sagittis et, consequat vestibulum, lacus. Mauris porttitor ullamcorper augue.</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Dialog NOTE: Dialog is not generated by UI in this demo so it can be visually styled in themeroller-->
  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Dialog</h2>
  <p><a href="#" id="dialog_link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span>Open Dialog</a></p>


  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Overlay and Shadow Classes <em>(not currently used in UI widgets)</em></h2>
  <div style="position: relative; width: 96%; height: 200px; padding:1% 4%; overflow:hidden;" class="fakewindowcontain">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  Nulla nec tortor. Donec id elit quis purus consectetur consequat. </p><p>Nam congue semper tellus. Sed erat dolor, dapibus sit amet, venenatis ornare, ultrices ut, nisi. Aliquam ante. Suspendisse scelerisque dui nec velit. Duis augue augue, gravida euismod, vulputate ac, facilisis id, sem. Morbi in orci. </p><p>Nulla purus lacus, pulvinar vel, malesuada ac, mattis nec, quam. Nam molestie scelerisque quam. Nullam feugiat cursus lacus.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec libero risus, commodo vitae, pharetra mollis, posuere eu, pede. Nulla nec tortor. Donec id elit quis purus consectetur consequat. </p><p>Nam congue semper tellus. Sed erat dolor, dapibus sit amet, venenatis ornare, ultrices ut, nisi. Aliquam ante. Suspendisse scelerisque dui nec velit. Duis augue augue, gravida euismod, vulputate ac, facilisis id, sem. Morbi in orci. Nulla purus lacus, pulvinar vel, malesuada ac, mattis nec, quam. Nam molestie scelerisque quam. </p><p>Nullam feugiat cursus lacus.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec libero risus, commodo vitae, pharetra mollis, posuere eu, pede. Nulla nec tortor. Donec id elit quis purus consectetur consequat. Nam congue semper tellus. Sed erat dolor, dapibus sit amet, venenatis ornare, ultrices ut, nisi. Aliquam ante. </p><p>Suspendisse scelerisque dui nec velit. Duis augue augue, gravida euismod, vulputate ac, facilisis id, sem. Morbi in orci. Nulla purus lacus, pulvinar vel, malesuada ac, mattis nec, quam. Nam molestie scelerisque quam. Nullam feugiat cursus lacus.orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec libero risus, commodo vitae, pharetra mollis, posuere eu, pede. Nulla nec tortor. Donec id elit quis purus consectetur consequat. Nam congue semper tellus. Sed erat dolor, dapibus sit amet, venenatis ornare, ultrices ut, nisi. </p>

   <!-- ui-dialog -->
   <div class="ui-overlay"><div class="ui-widget-overlay"></div><div class="ui-widget-shadow ui-corner-all" style="width: 302px; height: 152px; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 30px;"></div></div>
   <div style="position: absolute; width: 280px; height: 130px;left: 50px; top: 30px; padding: 10px;" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="background: none; border: 0;">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>


  <!-- ui-dialog -->
  <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>



  <h2 class="demoHeaders">Framework Icons (content color preview)</h2>
  <ul id="icons" class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-n"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-ne"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-ne"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-e"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span></li>

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-se"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-se"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-sw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-sw"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-nw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-nw"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-2-e-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-e-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-ne"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-ne"></span></li>

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-e"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-se"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-se"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-sw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-sw"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-1-nw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-nw"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-n-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-triangle-2-e-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-2-e-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-n"></span></li>

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-ne"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-ne"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-e"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-e"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-se"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-se"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-sw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-sw"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-1-nw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-1-nw"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-2-n-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-2-n-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-2-ne-sw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-2-ne-sw"></span></li>

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-2-e-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-2-se-nw"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-2-se-nw"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowstop-1-n"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowstop-1-e"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowstop-1-e"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowstop-1-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowstop-1-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowstop-1-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e"></span></li>





  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-n"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-n"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-s"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-arrow-4-diag"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4-diag"></span></li>

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-extlink"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-extlink"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-newwin"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-refresh"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-shuffle"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shuffle"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-transfer-e-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-transfer-e-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-transferthick-e-w"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-transferthick-e-w"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-folder-collapsed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-folder-open"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-document"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></li>

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-document-b"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document-b"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-note"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-note"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-mail-closed"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-mail-open"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-open"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-suitcase"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-suitcase"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-comment"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-comment"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-person"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-person"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-print"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-print"></span></li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-trash"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></li>
```

Comment: not working for me. Could this have something to do with my issues:
The jquery.datepick.ext.js module also defines a renderer that produces the standard structure, but using the ThemeRoller classes to help blend your datepicker with other jQuery UI components. Don't forget to load the appropriate ThemeRoller CSS, along with the corresponding local overrides:

Comment: this is for datepickER, the jQuery UI plugin. The person is asking about the datepick.s jQuery plugin that can be found at the link he gave.

Comment: @uv: datepickER only happens to be in the example that helps me apply themes. This does not mean that i ever suggested it as a solution to his problem. I simply suggested he have the css call at the top of his page.